# Reading data from MongoDB in batches and inserting it into a full-text search engine as fast as possible

Tags: python, mongodb, full-text-search, pymongo

Currently I use `collection.find()[i*batch:(i+1)*batch]` inside a for loop to iterate over a large MongoDB database of 2 billion documents. I then turn the returned cursor into a json object and send it to the full-text search engine with an api call.

Currently I'm able to retrieve and write 100k documents in 13 seconds. But I'm looking for a way to make this operation faster.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are only using MongoDB for storage and retrieval?  Every value of every field of every document in the collection is relevant to the text search?

Comment: @rickhg12hs MongoDB is only used for archiving purposes and search will be implemented with a full-text search engine. Only some of the fields are relevant so I actually define a projection and limit the number of fields returned. That improved speed considerably but I cannot further decrease the number of fields.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and your application will certainly involve programming, but my instincts tell me that significant efficiencies, if there are any, will be found in the overall architecture of your combined storage/search engine.